# what's the relationship between memcached slab and linux kernel slab

Tags: linux, memory, memcached, kernel

In linux kernel, there is a slab allocator for efficient memory management.
and I know there is a program in linux called 'memcached' to support memory caching for
MySQL or PHP or other programs. and they both seem to be using slab algorithm for
efficient memory management.

are these two slab algorithms same?
would it helpful if I understand the way how 'memcached' works for understanding how kernel slab allocator works?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

memcached use its own implementation of a slab allocator

Comment: thank you, even though implementation between kernel slab allocator and memcached are different, it seems they implement the same concept. so it might be helpful.